# is there any way to detect windows environment based function in our project?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

In my project i have to create platform independent code. My project(Based on .net framework 4.6.1 which i have convert it into .net core 3.1) was developed long ago and its based on windows environment now we convert it into Linux and Mc environment also. so is there any way to detect all windows specific classes so we can change it for Mc and Linux also or we just read the entire code and find each function and convert it. because its very time taken process to read entire code and change according to requirement so is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this article [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) first .

> so is there any way to detect all windows specific classes so we can change it for Mc and Linux also or we just read the entire code and find each function and convert it.

[.NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) is a tool that analyzes assemblies and provides a detailed report on .NET APIs that are missing for the applications or libraries to be portable on your specified targeted .

[try-convert](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert) is the tool that will help in migrating .NET Framework projects to .NET Core.

> Run on Linux and Mac platforms

`.NET Core` is cross-platform and it runs on `macOS`, `Linux`, and `Windows`. `.NET Core` supports the previously mentioned operating systems as your development workstation. With `.NET Core` you can target any application type that’s running on any platform. Visual Studio provides an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for Windows and macOS. You can also use **Visual Studio Code**, which runs on `macOS`, `Linux`, and `Windows`.

[.NET Core vs. .NET Framework for server apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)

Comment: if i am using Microsoft.win32 registry then how i convert it into for Mc or Linux

Comment: No, you could also use [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/) but you can't run the application on Linux and MacOS anymore.

Comment: All these OS have different operating mechanism. It's meaningless running `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` on Linux and MacOS.

Comment: ohk then what i will use in my code for that i run my code in linux, windows, Mc

Comment: Hi, @Gaurav, you need to reevaluate all functions in you codes which is only used to run on `Windows` . Now you need cross-platform design with `.NET Core` .

Comment: You will have a further understanding by following the articles I posted in answer.

Comment: is there any alternate api of Microsoft.Win32.Registry for cross plateform which is usefull for my project

Comment: There is no Linux/MacOS equivalent of the Windows `Registry`.  So There is no need and meaningless to run that magic api on other plateform.